# Run Web Application In Root Path In Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

When I run a Grails web application in Eclipse, it runs in tomcat at `localhost:8080/projectname`

Due to this, when my css needs to reference an image it needs to reference `/projectname/images/image.gif`. On the production server, however, the application will run at the root directory, so `projectname` can't be hardcoded into the path.

How can I debug the application in the root directory? Is this even the right way to think about the problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can reference the `projectname` by `request.getContextPath()` which should give you always the right application path.

Comment: Oh, no ... that wont work in a CSS file. Though if you have a structure like `/images/...`, `/css/...` etc, the URLs should be resolved correctly when referencing the image by `../images/...`.